Dipole transition in solid state systems and incident angle of photons
In solid state systems, there are energy transitions (absorption and emission of photons) that are photon polarization selective. I believe any sort of photon absorption based transitions comes down to the dipole term driven by the electric field component of the said photons. Does this mean if I want to activate certain transitions with the selection rule in mind, I have to pay close attention to the angle between the incident photon with a specific polarization and the dipole vector of the system you are trying to drive? For example, if your solid system has a bunch of dipoles aligned in the plane of the material surface, the probability of the dipoles transitions being driven is at its highest if the incident photons are perpendicular to the surface of the material?
Also, in the dipole picture, shouldn't linearly polarized light be a lot more effective than circularly polarized light when it comes to driving dipole transition, given that linear polarization could result in the electric field component of the light being perfectly aligned with the dipole moment. However, it seems that most solid state systems I have seen that exhibit photon polarization based dipole transitions usually get only driven by either left or right circularly polarized light.
